# Cannot get to the bottom of NoClassDefFoundError error in Groovy test

Tags: java, spring, testing, gradle, groovy

I am trying to run a very simple test in groovy and just when it starts to run the test I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spockframework/runtime/ErrorCollector

at com.imanage.runner.ExcelReportTests.Create simple client fetch report in excel(ExcelReportTests.groovy)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.spockframework.runtime.ErrorCollector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

I have tried to debug the test but I cant find where it is falling over, there is just no more information, can anyone explain why the test is failing?
Running in intelliJ if that makes a difference.

```
class ExcelReportTests extends Specification {
    def setup() {
        println "This will work"
    }
    def "Just a test"() {
        when:
            println "This is not printed"
        then:
            assert 1 == 1
    }
}
```

I have checked all the imports and they look fine, we use gradle for dependancy management and I cleared its cache too.

Comment: What happens if you run them normally from command line? If you didn't try that then do it.

Comment: Could you show your build.gradle please?

Comment: What version of Spock and which version of groovy?

Comment: RE command line, the tests run fine from command line, they build on jenkins they used to run from intelliJ too but that has not been tested for a long time
Spock: 1.1
Groovy: 2.4
Gradle: 4.6